# Symfony2 translation, parameter not working

Tags: datetime, symfony, translation

I'm having a problem with Symfony2's translator.

I have a DateTimeFormatter class (simplified here):

```
<?php

namespace Project\CommonBundle\Util;

use DateTime;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class DateTimeFormatter
{
    private $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function format(DateTime $datetime, array $options = array())
    {
        $delta = time() - $datetime->getTimestamp();

        return $this->translator->trans('datetime_formatter.seconds_ago', array('%seconds%', $delta);
    }
}
```

With translation file:

```
datetime_formatter:
    seconds_ago: %seconds% seconds ago
```

And I configured it as a service:

```
parameters:
    datetime_formatter.class: Skepin\CommonBundle\Util\DateTimeFormatter
services:
    common.util.datetime_formatter:
            class: %datetime_formatter.class%
            arguments: [@translator]
```

The problem is: when I use it, the text displayed is `%seconds% seconds ago`, the parameter is not replaced. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem resolved:

```
return $this->translator->trans('datetime_formatter.seconds_ago', array('%seconds%' => $delta);
```

instead of:

```
return $this->translator->trans('datetime_formatter.seconds_ago', array('%seconds%', $delta);
```

Stupid error...